# Netbeans: How to enable Save for Git-controlled project?

Tags: git, netbeans, save, repo

Background:
Apache NetBeans IDE 15, Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS
I have a pre-existing, work-related, Java project that was recently added to git version control (Azure Devops) for the first time. I have successfully worked on this project before it was version controlled.

Problem:

- Now that it’s been git’ed (and I created a local repo copy), when the project is open in Netbeans, the File > Save option is greyed out. I cannot save the project or individual files (seems true for all files & types in the project).
- If I copy/paste any of the files into another directory (like ~/), then I can modify and save those files just fine.
- In Netbeans, if I right-click the file (in the “Projects” window dir tree) > History > Show History, then I see a table with columns Date, Revision, User, and Message. On top are two, mostly blank (only Date and Revision = “local” are filled in), rows since my last commit. There is nothing identifying these lines as commits or anything else, and I can’t find any documentation explaining what this “History” is.
- I suspect that Netbeans is trying to force me to use its Git integration by removing my ability to Save files. Integration can be nice, but I don't want to be forced to use it.
- I read through https://netbeans.apache.org/kb/docs/ide/git.html but found nothing about disabling my Save button.
- I asked around, and my coworker circumvented this by adding a directory above his project directory, and then making that the git folder. This way, when you open the project in Netbeans, NB doesn’t see the .git directory because it is outside of the project. Seems unfortunate that I have to change my repo root just for Netbeans.

Questions:

- What are the mostly-empty rows in History? Is Netbeans auto-commiting when I close the project (seems - unlikely)?
- Are they auto- save points? < Is that part of Git or the Netbeans project?
- Are they auto- add/stages? < This would be bad, basically forcing me to add/stage all edited files at once?
- How do I tell which is which, since Netbeans doesn’t give any indication at all as to what these "History" points are?

Most Importantly! How do I disable this “feature” so that I can save files, and do some basic Git’in from the Terminal?

Comment: For clarification: (1) "_the File > Save option is greyed out_" - this should be the case if there are no unsaved changes (regardless of whether you are using Git or not). That is how NetBeans works. Are you saying there are unsaved changes in a file - and the save option is still greyed out? (2) the `History > Show History` functionality in NetBeans is also completely separate from whether or not you are using Git or any other VCS (version control system). It's a "pure NetBeans" feature, and probably not relevant to this question. Think of it as "VCS lite" in NetBeans.

Comment: (3) Go to `Tools > Options > Editor > Autosave`. Is that feature activated?

Comment: @andrewJames Autosave is NOT activated. Yes, there are unsaved changes. For example, I added/modified 20+ lines to a .fxml file. The file appears blue in the Project tree and has a small blue rectangular shape next to the immediate directory and all directories above that, both of which indicate Netbeans knows the file has been changed.

Comment: In the end I re-installed Netbeans, and I haven't had this problem since. Also the comments I made (in the previous comment) about the blue file highlighting were incorrect. This file highlighting references if the changes are committed, not saved.